# Unopened unrefrigerated kraft shredded cheese

Tags: cheese

Unopened kraft shredded cheese left in dark and unrefrigerated for 2 weeks. Is it safe to eat?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. My guess is "no", but what temperature was it kept at?

Comment: Even in fridge, the stuff eventually goes moldy. Of course, most cheese molds are not very toxic. Then again *Listeria monocytogenes* probably likes warm temperatures better than cold ones: https://www.cdc.gov/listeria/

Answer (score 1):

The cheese will not be safe to eat if it has been at room temperature for two weeks. On the package, it should say "KEEP REFRIGERATED". Hy-Vee states the food should be refrigerated [here](https://www.hy-vee.com/grocery/PD14436789/Kraft-Finely-Shredded-Mild-Cheddar-Cheese). The  note is there for a reason, the cheese will spoil if at room temperature for too long.

Kraft includes the note because they know it is likely if someone doesn't keep the shredded cheese refrigerated, the person could get sick and sue them for not disclosing it needs to be refrigerated.

It's certainly possible you won't get sick if you eat it. But two weeks is a long time and I recommend **not eating it**.

Comment: I agree with Caleb cheese should not be left out that long. However if it is in the refrigerator and has mold on it you just cut the mold off. It is perfectly safe to eat.